# How to get count of a column with key-pair value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas and working on some exercise.

The question is to find the number of items that have more than 3 types. I am confused how to get the types(keys) from `type` column.

Besides, is it a proper way for Pandas to store kv pair in a single column? Thanks!

```
shopid  name        type
1       item1       {S: 10, M: 10, L: 10}
2       item2       {S: 10, M: 10}
2       item3       {S: 10, M: 10, L: 10, XL: 10}
3       item1       {S: 10, M: 10, L: 10}
3       item2       {S: 10, M: 10}
4       item3       {S: 10, M: 10, L: 10, XL: 10}
4       item1       {S: 10, M: 10, L: 10}
4       item2       {S: 10, M: 10}
4       item4       {S: 10, M: 10, L: 10, XL: 10, XXL: 10}
```

**Expected output**

`2`

where item3 and item4 have more than 3 types

Comment: Is `type` a `str` or `dict`? *"Is it a proper way for `pandas` to store kv pair in a single column?"* - short answer, **no**: You should avoid storing anything besides the basic dtypes (`str`, `int`, `float`, `datetime`...) in `pandas` as it can get complicated.  These should have been 5 diffierent columns of `S... XXL` with the individual values in rows.

Comment: Is this a pandas dataframe?  And what is in the Type column, is it a dictionary or string?   I aggree with @r.ook comment above.

Comment: @r.ook it's `str`. Agree with your point that it's better to save in different columns. At the end the exercise asked for improvement for the dataset and I guess this is why the values are intentionally put into single column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way, using the str accessor to look at the dictionary in column 'type', then use nunique to count the number of unique names:

```
df.loc[df['type'].str.len() > 3, 'name'].nunique()
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: Thanks! I checked the data type of  `type` is actually `str` and it works for me.

Comment: Are you sure your `dtype` is `str`? If so this solution wouldn't work because `str.len()` would have returned double digits for all of these.  If this work they they are `dict`s` with `dtype='o'`.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC , considering below as your dataframe , :

```
d = {'shopid': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 4, 6: 4, 7: 4, 8: 4},
 'name': {0: 'item1',
  1: 'item2',
  2: 'item3',
  3: 'item1',
  4: 'item2',
  5: 'item3',
  6: 'item1',
  7: 'item2',
  8: 'item4'},
 'type': {0: {'S': 10, 'M': 10, 'L': 10},
  1: {'S': 10, 'M': 10},
  2: {'S': 10, 'M': 10, 'L': 10, 'XL': 10},
  3: {'S': '10', 'M': 10, 'L': 10},
  4: {'S': 10, 'M': 10},
  5: {'S': 10, 'M': 10, 'L': 10, 'XL': 10},
  6: {'S': 10, 'M': 10, 'L': 10},
  7: {'S': 10, 'M': 10},
  8: {'S': 10, 'M': 10, 'L': 10, 'XL': 10, 'XXL': 10}}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

---

You can convert the dictionary column as a DataFrame and group on `shopid` and get the first values which ignores NaN , then take sum of notna on axis=1 and compare:

```
output = (pd.DataFrame(df['type'].tolist()).groupby(df['name']).first()
          .notna().sum(1).gt(3).sum())
print(output)
#2
```

Comment: @r.ook I was under the assumption OP is looking for unique keys per group greater than 3.. what you say can also be achieved by `df['type'].str.len().gt(3).sum()`  , without `apply` :) but that returns 3 ... May be I am wrong

Comment: You are right, I missed that detail.  I think the `groupby` would have been for `name` though?

Comment: @r.ook thanks I missed that , corrected the grouper column , Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your column `type` is not a proper `dict`, but `str`. There is  though a trick you can try, by observing that number of `types` is actually equals to number of `:` you have:

```
df=df[df['type'].str.count(':')>3]
```

It should help you to select rows that have more than three types.
Additionally, I agree with the comments about the datatype in a dataframe, having k,v as dict in a column is not a good option at time.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: Assuming your data is in a dataframe called* `df`

Firstly for your purpose,
You can remove duplicates in your DF by doing,

```
df.drop_duplicates()
```

optionally reset the index using `df.drop_duplicates().reset_index()`

Then you can add a slack column by doing,

```
df['type_count'] = df.apply(lambda r: len(r['type']), axis = 1)
```

Then you can crunch, delete the slack column and find the number of rows like so,

```
print(df[df['type_count']>3].iloc[:,:-1].shape[0])
```

`df[df['type_count']>3]` finds all items > 3 dictionary elements, `.iloc[:,:-1]` removes the slack column and `shape[0]` selects the rows only.

Hope this helps.